# I am trying to get the _id from the bucket Grid FS to another mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scope, this, gridfs

I am trying to get the _id from the bucket Grid FS to another mongo document.

These are the constructor object:

```
let Upload = function(data, file, userid) {
  this.data = data
  this.errors = []
  this.userid = userid
  this.file=file  
}
```

here is the function I am having trouble with and the problem is that the this.data is undefined even though I am using a => function which shouldn't change the this keyword source:

```
Upload.prototype.create = async function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.cleanUp()
    this.data.file.forEach((element,index)=> {


      fs.createReadStream('./uploads/'+element.filename).
        pipe(uploadStream= bucket.openUploadStream(element._id,'./uploads/'+element.filename)).
        on('error', function(error) {
          assert.ifError(error);
          console.log(error)
        }).
        on('finish', function() {
          console.log('Done');                          
          console.log('fs.files._id:'+uploadStream.id)
          try{
          this.data.file[index]._id=uploadStream.id //this is line 62
          }catch(e)
          {console.log('error on line 62',e)}

        })
    })
    this.validate()
    console.log('data file filename:'+this.data.file[0].filename)//why is this defined and working...
    console.log('data file id:'+this.data.file[0]._id)//but this one is not

    if (!this.errors.length) {
      // save upload into database


        uploadsCollection.insertOne(this.data).then(() => {
          resolve()

      }).catch(() => {
        this.errors.push("Please try again later.")
        reject(this.errors)
      })
    } else {
      reject(this.errors)
    }
  })
}
```

this is in the cleanup() function:

```
this.data = {
    title: this.data.title.trim(),
    comment: this.data.comments.trim(),
    file: this.file,
    createdDate: new Date(),
    author: ObjectID(this.userid)
  }
```

Here is the console:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node db.js`
{ fieldname: 'myFiles',
  originalname: 'party.xlsx',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/octet-stream' }
size of file: 8375 
ok size
data file filename:party.xlsx
data file id:undefined
Done
fs.files._id:5df327ebc7686e05e82851fa
error on line 62 TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at GridFSBucketWriteStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\models\Upload.js:95:21)
    at GridFSBucketWriteStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs-stream\upload.js:284:13
    at result (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:75:17)
    at session.endSession (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:64:11)
    at ClientSession.endSession (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sessions.js:135:41)
    at executeCallback (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:59:17)
    at insertDocuments (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert_one.js:34:21)
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:129:55)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (C:\Users\colin\Documents\gelc-upload\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:270:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, in line 62 ... this.data.file[index]._id=uploadStream.id //this is line 62, the this was referring to the fs which is the GridFS. I moved the line outside of the on.(finish), but still in the foreach loop, it worked.